# animation.css and Foundation

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, zurb-foundation

I would like to achieve in the home of my web site the effect that you can see on this (http://foundation.zurb.com/learn/features.html) page when it loaded (the rocket comes from below, other images from above...)

Even here (http://7.pdvop2sz.z8.ru/highland/1.3/) we can see this animation in the texts entering from the left ...

Looking in the code I noticed that in both sites (the site that use Foundation and the other with Bootstrap) the elements that have this effect have the follow class

```
class="animated slideInLeft third"

class="largerocket animated fadeInUpBig"
```

So looking a bit 'on the web I have seen this script: Animate.css

perhaps this is what they use?  Or there are other libraries (maybe native in Foundation, or jQuery) with which to implement these effects to incoming items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. you are right, Its a CSS plugin.

**Some of them are listed below.**

http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

http://www.justinaguilar.com/animations/

http://labs.bigroomstudios.com/libraries/animo-js